# Как оформить прямую речь, находящуюся в середине предложения?

Tags: прямая-речь, цитата

Как следует оформить слова *добрый день* в данном предложении?

*Субъект перешёл из состояния бездействия в состояние умеренной активности и сказал «добрый день» собравшимся рабочим.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что можно оставить всё так, как есть у автора вопроса, тем более что структура предложения к этому располагает.

> **Примечание.** Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
> *Это **«не хочу»** поразило Антона Прокофьевича* (Г.); <...> *С криком **«Спасайте детей!»** юноша бросился в горящее здание.*

*Если бы он просто **сказал "добрый день"**, было бы не удивительно* (Владислав Крапивин. Мальчик со шпагой).

*Поздоровались они. Только Иванка **сказал "добрый день"**, вылетело у него из головы слово. Никак не может вспомнить!* (белорусская народная сказка "Потерянное слово").

> Маша сказала Мышонку:
> — Утром надо всем **говорить «доброе утро»**. А вечером надо всем **говорить «спокойной ночи»**. И тогда все будут с тобой дружить.
> Побежал Мышонок к зайцам. Всем зайцам **сказал «доброе утро»**. И папе, и маме, и бабушке, и дедушке, и маленькому Зайчонку.
> Улыбнулись зайцы и дали Мышонку морковку.
> Побежал Мышонок к белкам. Всем белкам **сказал «доброе утро»**. И папе, и маме, и бабушке, и дедушке, и даже маленькому Бельчонку.
> [С. Л. Прокофьева. Сказка о невоспитанном мышонке](https://sites.google.com/site/skazkidladoskolnikov/home/skazki-dla-detej-4-5-let/skazka-o-nevospitannom-mysonke)

[Прямая речь внутри слов автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159)

Comment: А чего не с прописной? Всё-таки начало высказывания.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнение** по поводу прописной-строчной
*А чего не с прописной? Всё-таки начало высказывания.*

У Розенталя в первом примере со строчной ("не хочу"; и мы не знаем, начало это высказывания или нет), а во втором примере — с прописной ("Спасайте детей!").

У Лопатина ([§ 143](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85/)):

> Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента, выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы)...

Я бы и во втором примере написала со строчной, потому что это уже часть предложения, а все слова внутри обычного предложения начинаются с маленькой буквы (кроме имен собственных).

Вот как оформлен крик "ура" у известных авторов.

• Анатолий Приставкин (1992):
*И мы выстрелили, а потом **с криком «ура!»** пошли на врагов в атаку...*

• Константин Симонов (1978):
*...когда дело пошло на лад, выскакивать из них **с криком «ура!».***

• Валентина Осеева (1969):
*И она, Динка, **с криком «ура!»** тоже кого-то била...*

• Сергей Залыгин (1967):
*...с утра до ночи бегают **с криком «ура»**, с винтовками наперевес...*

• Юрий Нагибин (1942):
*... как они метко бьют из-за брустверов, как **с криком «Ура!»** наступают под огнем...*

Comment: В первом примере не так прямолинейно, "не хочу" означает отказ. У Розенталя много примеров и есть пояснения, ловите: https://i.imgur.com/bGgPCNW.png А Лопатин решил всё упростить.

Comment: *Я бы и во втором примере написала со строчной, потому что это уже часть предложения* — это как в том случае с закрытием оборота в кавычках. Плохая логика, текст-то чужеродный, сплавлять его с основным предложением не стоит.

Comment: Разное есть оформление. Думаю, что это авторский выбор. *И тогда лошадиный с криком **"врешь, гад!"** бросился к прижавшемуся к стене...* (Ю. Домбровский); *Серега собрал смолу с прибрежных избитых льдом елок, нагрел ее в банке, и с криком **«Накосить они тебе накосят!»** долил бензину...* (М. Тарковский); *Я с перепугу толкнул дверь и с криком **«прыгайте»** вывалился на бетон...* (А. Хургин); *Выскочил с криком **«Эврика!»***  (Э. Лимонов).

Comment: Розенталь на то и создал справочник, чтобы не было разного оформления (об этом сказано в предисловии). Мне нравится его вариант, он логичный: если начало предложения, то прописная, если нет, то нет. Мы бы точно так действовали, если бы цитировали из письменного источника (буквы нельзя менять). Так чего же при устной речи поступать иначе?

Comment: Гоголевский пример, который приводит Розенталь, это опровергает, дважды: *— Что ж? идем или нейдем? — **Не хочу.** Это **"не хочу"** поразило Антона Прокофьевича. Он уже думал, что убедительное представление его совершенно склонило этого, впрочем, достойного человека, но вместо того услышал решительное **"не хочу"**.*

Comment: Вот: *Выход в свет «Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации» (1956 г.) в значительной мере содействовал упорядочению правописания и **устранению разнобоя, создававшего множество затруднений** в работе издательств, а также в школьном преподавании. <...> В практике издательств и сейчас еще нередки случаи пунктуационного разнобоя, требующие регламентации. Настоящее пособие представляет собой попытку установить возможное единство в пользовании правилами пунктуации.*

Comment: "Не хочу" имеет значение отказа. Можно услышать выражения типа: *Убери своё "не хочу".* А человек мог вообще не говорить эту фразу. Оно уже как бы устойчивое, здесь прописная не кстати.

Comment: То же и с "не могу", "не буду".